# Adding Facebook's image and meta description retrieval capabilities to a WordPress post

Tags: custom-field, images, post-meta, urls

When a URL is shared on Facebook, Facebook is able to automatically pull a relevant image and the meta description for use in the post.

Would it be possible to code similar functionality into WordPress such that if a URL were added to a custom field within a WordPress post, WordPress would be able to pull in a relevant image and the meta description?

Comment: Probably. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not tried anything. I wasn't sure how it worked so I was hoping for an explanation of the general approach first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Facebook uses [the Open Graph protocol](https://ogp.me/) for this. Basically, a site that provides certain Open Graph meta tags can have the data that these tags refer to appear nicely formatted on Facebook.

Example from [the Open Graph protocol site](https://ogp.me/#metadata):

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

You could probably use a similar approach if this suits your use case.

For sites without these tags, Facebook [does indicate that](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#markup):

> Without these tags, the Facebook Crawler uses internal heuristics to make a best guess about the title, description, and preview image for your content.

If your question is centered around how this can be achieved, things might get a little more complicated. You could try an approach in which, based on a WordPress post URL, you perform a `GET` request on the associated blog's [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) that fetches the metadata of that particular post for you.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for the explanation. I guess I'll need to figure out how to use the REST API in the most sensible way.